# MS SQL Datawarehouse performance improvements for non-unique key table

Tags: sql-server-2000, data-warehouse

We recently updated our DataWarehouse (a MS SQL 2000 database) to include a new table to control the level of access users had to information in all of the other tables. Without going into too much detail, the new table has a user ID, and a list of account IDs that they can access. All of our tables within the DataWarehouse have had a corresponding view created, and we've asked our users to use these views to access the data (and thus limits their view based on the level of access in the initial Access Control table).

For complex queries which use many of these views, we obviously have a problem whereby the same access control table is joined on many times. We can't do a lot about that at the moment as there are many queries we don't have control over accessing this resource. We need therefore to make any changes we can on the box itself to optimise the speed of access.

The Datawarehouse is only updated overnight, and to be honest the time this takes is irrelevant - insert speed is not required, only select. We can also rebuild the indexes if necassary.

The problem we have is, despite having an index on this non-unique record (the UserID column), when doing execution plan traces we see that Table Scans are used instead of Index Seek, which I understand is basically ignoring the index. This is leading to horrific performance implications - a query that last week took say a minute to execute can now take 10, and some are pushing an hour.

All of the other views that now reference this table join onto the non-indexed column (the account ID), and then the number of accounts returned are filtered out based on the NT ID of the user.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what we can do to improve the performance? Either in the short term (things we can change on the infrastructure side), or longer term (changes to the database schema, we can't do this easily though given the nature of how the database is used).

Thanks!

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you don't mention what reporting tool you're using (I have the impression that users write their own queries?) or what volume of data you have, but two longer-term enhancements would be:

1. Upgrade to SQL2008: SQL2000 is no longer supported and performance, tools and general features have all improved significantly in newer versions
2. Use a reporting tool like SSRS, Business Objects or Cognos that includes support for user-level data visibility, caching for performance etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you can you should provide your users with a store procedure that acts as follows:

1. create a temp table the "old way" (without the joins)
2. filter the results that the user allowed to see

so you will only join on the relevant data.

It will improve the query time considerably (depends on the ratio between the size of the db and the amount of relevant data) and will not require a change to the db scheme.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an index on the UserId, but not the AccountId that is actually used in joins.

If I understood your indexes correctly, you might try a couple of things:

- Add an index on AccountId - experiment with clustered/non-clustered to see which has a better impact on performance.
- Update the UserId index to include the AccountId - this may work better if the 2 fields are always used together.

Also, when reviewing the execution plan, look at the seek details - what is it seeking?  That may help you further refine the ideal indexes for your system.

Good Luck!